# Error trying to set svn password on Hudson

Tags: svn, hudson

After filling the Repository URL, User name and password I get the following error.

Does anyone knows how to fix it?

No authentication was attemped.
FAILED: svn: Operation cancelled

org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNCancelException: svn: Operation cancelled
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$DescriptorImpl.postCredential(SubversionSCM.java:1421)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$DescriptorImpl.doPostCredential(SubversionSCM.java:1317)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:160)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:76)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:73)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:30)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:436)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:186)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:30)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:436)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:354)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:114)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:45)
    at winstone.ServletConfiguration.execute(ServletConfiguration.java:249)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.forward(RequestDispatcher.java:335)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:378)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:91)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:83)
    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:195)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:368)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:155)
    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:195)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:368)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.forward(RequestDispatcher.java:333)
    at winstone.RequestHandlerThread.processRequest(RequestHandlerThread.java:244)
    at winstone.RequestHandlerThread.run(RequestHandlerThread.java:150)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 1):

See Hudson issue [2073](http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-2073)  The Hudson users mailing list would be a better place to get help.